# ie9 standards mode, iframes, and dom manip

Tags: javascript, iframe, jquery-ui-dialog, internet-explorer-9

IE9 (standards mode) does not allow you to manipulate iframes in the DOM at all.  If you use jQueryUI Dialog, or jQuery's .wrap() function to wrap content that happens to have an iframe in it IE9 will blow up.  In fact you don't even need jQuery, plain old JS will work just fine (see below).

I'd like to know what people think about this since Microsoft [says they do this on purpose to address a memory leak](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622929%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

We're not sure what to do about this.  Putting all our docs that use iframes into Quirks mode seems wrong.  But we're not sure what the alternatives are.  Any ideas?  TIA.

Javascript Sample Code:

```
       <p id="after"></p>
```

..put iframe here...

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //uncomment code below in IE9 standards mode to see error
            //document.getElementById("after").appendChild(document.getElementById("iframe"));
        </script>
```

Comment: where's the element with id 'iframe'?

Comment: The MSDN document you've cited concerns IFRAMES that are not actually in a document tree. But your question doesn't mention that you're trying to do this on an IFRAME that's not in a tree. Is that what you're trying to do? What does "blow up" mean exactly? What is the error message?

Comment: sorry, I added markup that got mangled when I published...  If you manipulate an iframe in the DOM at all, IE9 will blow up.  Wrap it with divs, or move it and BOOOM!  The error message(s) fyi, is that native JS objects like "Object" don't exist.

Comment: Ensuring that you remove the iframe directly and not an element containing the iframe solved this issue for me. To link an answer ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/9526904/1257652

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running into this issue I've succumbed to putting the browser into quirks mode:

```
        Response.AddHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=8");
```

Any other solutions are definitely welcome since like tengoal I suspect this isn't the best option even though **it works**.